# What if x<b in a^(-1)*(x-b) mod m?

Tags: encryption

I'm trying to write a code which decrypts any `Affine cipher`.

Now, I found that the decryption function is :

`y = a^(-1) * (x-b) mod 26`

The problem is : when `x` is smaller than `b` the answer is negative.

I know that it is a Math question rather than a Code question, but I hope that there are some nice guys who may help me.

Comment: You can use this identity: (-x) mod n == (n - (x % n)) % n

Comment: I don't get it..

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a question that straddles maths and programming.

Firstly mathematicians and programmers use "mod" somewhat differently.

Mathematicians use it as a statement about the equation they have just written.  When they say "a = b + c mod m" what they mean is that "a = b + c" in modulo m arithmetic.

Programmers on the other hand use mod as an operator that provides the remainder after integer division.

Secondly there are multiple ways of defining integer division "floored division", "truncated division" and "euclidian division" and hence multiple ways of defning the modulo operator.

Unfortunately what you need for your algorithm is the "remainder after floored division" but what your programming language is giving you is the "remainder after truncated division.

One possible fix is to simply add an if statement.

```
if (y < 0) y += 26
```

Comment: or `((x - b) mod 26 + 26) mod 26` to get rid of the `if` statement. There are a few other options, but using `((x mod n) + n) mod n` is a method that should generally work.

Comment: Assuming the compiler doesn't optimise it out this saves a branch but adds a second mod operation. Whether that is better probablly depends on the CPU target.